# Parameter validation failed: Invalid bucket name in aws s3api put-object-acl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried to change the ACL configuration of a file in s3 through the command line, but it showed the error

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name
```

The problem is that the file I want to access has a structure such as follows:

```
data/folder1/folder2/folder3/file
```

I tried to access using the code

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket s3://data/folder1/folder2/folder3/ --key file --acl public-read
```

How should I specify this?

Thank you very much!
Lluc

Comment: What's the actual name of your bucket?

Comment: flomics-public/lluc/ext-controls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bucket name doesn't need the `s3://` prefix when using `put-object-acl`:

```
$ aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket flomics-public --key 'lluc/ext-controls/data/folder1/folder2/folder3/file' --acl public-read
```

Comment: Okay, I thought that the bucket was until the file. Thank you very much!

Comment: @lluc bucket is always the bucket name, whereas the key is the full path to the file. You might it useful to review the docs on this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html